# Can I upload Java class as a Jar file in Static Resource and use that Java class components in Apex class?

Tags: apex, java, static-resources

I have piece of code in Java language, I need to use it in apex class. Let me know if I can upload Java class as Static Resource and use it in Apex class?

Answer (score 2):

No, while Apex does get compiled down to java bytecode, java is not able to be used within Salesforce.

We have Javascript and Apex, and that's all (setting Heroku aside, on which you could use any language you please).